# Swift Error Handling: Authentication System

Tags: swift

I am having problem displaying custom error message on Swift.

The scenario is basic user authentication with Dictionary data, input entered is validated with the Dictionary data, if username and password matches, return true, else an error message as "**Invalid Credentials**" with `AuthenticationError` appears (argument message `CustomErrors` enum)

Here is the code I have come up with so far:

```
import Foundation

//Editable code starts here


let authDict:Dictionary = ["admin":"admin123","user":"someone123","guest":"guest999","you":"yourpass","me":"mypass190"]

//create CustomErrors enum
public enum CustomErrors: Error {
    case AuthenticationError(message:String)
    //case invalidCredentials
}

extension CustomErrors: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self{
            //case .invalidCredentials:
            //   return NSLocalizedString("Invalid Credentials", comment: "Invalid Credentials")
        //return "Invalid Credentials"
        case .AuthenticationError(message:let message):
            print(message)
            return "Invalid Credentials"
        }
    }
}
// create authenticate(userName:user,pass:pass) with return type Boolean
func authenticate(user:String,pass:String) -> Bool{
    print(user)
    print(pass)
    for(u,p) in authDict {
        if((u == user) && (p == pass)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    print("Invalid Credentials")
    return false
}
//Editable code ends here
//Uneditable code starts here
let stdout = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: stdout, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: stdout)!

guard let user = readLine() else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let pass = readLine() else { fatalError("Bad input") }

do{
    let result = try authenticate(user:user,pass:pass)
    fileHandle.write((result ? "1" : "0").data(using: .utf8)!)
}catch CustomErrors.AuthenticationError(let message){
    fileHandle.write(message.data(using: .utf8)!)
}
//Uneditable code ends here
```

The above code works perfect for all positive test cases like :

```
 1. "admin":"admin123"
 2. "user":"someone123"
 3. "guest":"guest999"
 4. "you":"yourpass"
 5. "me":"mypass190"
```

The output is `1` for all above, but for negative test cases, I should get `Invalid Credentials` printed as output, instead I get `0`

I am not sure what I am missing in the `CustomErrors` enum but its not working.

How do I fix my editable code to work with the below uneditable code, what should I add/delete to achieve the end result:

```
do{
    let result = try authenticate(user:user,pass:pass)
    fileHandle.write((result ? "1" : "0").data(using: .utf8)!)
}catch CustomErrors.AuthenticationError(let message){
    fileHandle.write(message.data(using: .utf8)!)
}
```

Comment: What do you get printed on the console? The func authenticate does not throw the CustomErrors you’re trying to catch in your not editable code.

Comment: Not related, but `authDict` is a Dictionary. Looping on it `for(u,p) in authDict` doesn't make sense. It's not efficient. Instead: `guard let savedPassword = authDict[user] else { return false } return savedPassword == pass`?

Comment: @OresteRiccardoNatale I see either `0` or `1` printed on the console for negative or positive test cases

Comment: @LarmeI am new to Dictionary, never used it before, quick google search gave me for loop to go thru Dictionary, the `guard let...` really worked! Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `authenticate` function as:

```swift
func authenticate(user:String,pass:String) throws -> Bool{
    print(user)
    print(pass)
    guard authDict[user] == pass else {
        throw CustomErrors.AuthenticationError(message: "Invalid Credentials")
    }
    return true
}
```

Now the function throws a `CustomErrors` error if `user` and `pass` do not match those stored in the `authDict Dictionary`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you kind sir, I replaced my `func authenticate` with the solution above and it got the desired output! Thanks again!